# How do I loop over this xml structure and create an array from it in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, foreach

I have an xml node which is structured like this:

```
<ItemDimensions>
    <Height Units="hundredths-inches">42</Height>
    <Length Units="hundredths-inches">752</Length>
    <Weight Units="hundredths-pounds">69</Weight>
    <Width Units="hundredths-inches">453</Width>
</ItemDimensions>
```

How do I loop over this XML and get the attributes, units and values into an array?

e.g. I want to build an array which looks like this:

```
$itemDimensions = array(
    array('height','hundredths-inches',24),
    array('length,','hundredths-inches',752), 
    array('weight','hundredths-pounds',69),
    array('width','hundredths-inches',453),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be ok:

```
<?php 

$x = '<ItemDimensions>
       <Height Units="hundredths-inches">42</Height>
       <Length Units="hundredths-inches">752</Length>
       <Weight Units="hundredths-pounds">69</Weight>
       <Width Units="hundredths-inches">453</Width>
      </ItemDimensions>';

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($x);
$dimensions = $xml->getElementsByTagName('ItemDimensions');

$array = array();

$i = 0;
while(is_object($node = $dimensions->item($i))){
    foreach($node->childNodes as $n){
        if($n->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            $array[] = array($n->nodeName,$n->getAttribute('Units'),$n->nodeValue);
        }        
    }
    $i++;
}
var_dump($array);
?>
```

Comment: This is some re-useable code. https://phpro.org/examples/XML-To-Array-With-PHP.html